# Decompose a two-manifold into the union of Orientation Reversal Pairs

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology

Consider an open two dimensional manifold $M$, with its nontrivial boundary $\partial M$.    Let $R$ be an orientation reversal transformation operator which flips the orientation of $M$ while keeps its boundary $\partial M$ fixed. For example, if $M=D^2$ is the north hemisphere with its boundary being the equator, then $R(M)$ is the south hemisphere and its boundary is still the equator. Then we can glue $M$ and $R(M)$ into a whole sphere
$$D^2 \cup_{S^1} R(D^2) = S^2$$

As another example, let $M=\mathrm{Mobius}$ be a Mobius bend. $\partial \mathrm{(Mobius)}= S^1$. Then R(\mathrm{Mobius})=\mathrm{Mobius}, and
$$\mathrm{Mobius} \cup_{S^1} R(\mathrm{Mobius}) = KB$$
where $KB$ is a Klein bottle.

> My question is whether there exists a two dimensional open manifold $M$, such that 
>   $$M \cup_{\partial M} R(M) = \mathbf{RP}^2$$

~

> A more general question is whether there exist other two dimensional non-orientable manifolds $\Sigma$ (apart from $KB$) such that the decomposition below happens? 
>   $$M \cup_{\partial M} R(M) = \Sigma$$

Comment: Reversing orientation on a nonorientable manifold is meaningless. In any case, think about the equation $\chi(\Sigma)= 2\chi(M)$. If you know what a connected sum is, try to show that your $M$ exists if and only if $\chi(\Sigma)$ is even.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Thanks! I am not quite sure about the first sentence, since it suggests that the two Mobius bends that composes into a KB are not orientation reversal of each other. But one can indeed glue two crosscaps into a  KB where two crosscuts are orientation reversal of each other. I agree with your second comment, which suggest that there is no M such that $M\cup R(M)= RP^2$ because $\chi(RP^2)=1$. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Since Möbius bands are not orientable, they have no orientations to reverse. Hence it makes no sense to talk about two Möbius bands being "orientation reversals of each other".

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks! Maybe I shall not call the $R(Mobius)$ as orientation reversal of $Mobius$. $R(Mobius)$ on my side is defined as follows. Consider the $Mobius$ as a cylinder $I \times S^1$ with two boundaries at $z=0$ and $z=1$,  and glue the $z=0$ boundary with a cross cap. So the boundary of the Mobius bend is at $z=1$.  Then $R(Mobius)$ is defined as reversal in the $z$ direction, so that the boundary is at $z=-1$. Maybe this is not called a orientation reversal.